# How to display json without column names pandas/python?

Tags: python, pandas, to-json

We query a df by below code:

```
json.loads(df.reset_index(drop=True).to_json(orient='table'))
```

The output is:

```
{"index": [ 0, 1 ,2, 3, 4],
 "col1": [ "250"],
 "col2": [ "1"],
 "col3": [ "223"],
 "col4": [ "2020-06-12 14:55"]
}
```

We need the output should be like this:

```
[ "250", "1", "223", "2020-06-12 14:55"],[.....][.....]
```

Comment: You can use `zip`. What would be the values in `[.....][.....]`? Please add [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
json.loads(df.reset_index(drop=True).to_json(orient='values'))
```

change `table` into `values` solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you call a "json" (there is no such data type) is a Python dictionary.  Extract the values for the keys of interest using list comprehension:

```
x = .... # Your dictionary
[x[col][0] for col in x if col.startswith("col")]
#['250', '1', '223', '2020-06-12 14:55']
```

Comment: `json.loads(df.reset_index(drop=True).to_json(orient='values')) `
change `table` into `values` solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

We convert json to dataframe and we remove column name.

```
pd.Dataframe(json_source,header='False')
```

Then we convert it to json formate

```
df.to_json(orient='table')
```

Comment: `json.loads(df.reset_index(drop=True).to_json(orient='values')) `
change `table` into `values` solved my problem.